# Split a string with size less than 1MB

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, string, c#-4.0

Can someone suggest how to split a string into arrayLists with a condition that each string size of the arraylist should be less than 1 MB.

I have the string values provided in a string variable. I need to traverse the string values and then check the string size should be always > 1MB and if the  size is more than 1MB then split the string data and store it in sub-strings of the array-lists.

Can someone suggest how can I implement it in my below code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System;
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {


        String[][] TextFile = new String[5][] { { "Mike", "Amy" }, { "Mary", "Albert" } } ;


        for (int i = 0; i < TextFile.Length; i++)
        {
            TextFile[i] = new String[i + 1];
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < TextFile.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Length of row {0} is {1}", i, TextFile[i].Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use  `System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(string); ` for each entry and add up the returned value, by using this and checking that the total size is less than 1Mb you should be fine

Comment: You should probably define what you mean by size. Size in memory? Size on disk? Size over a network stream? If either of the last two, you also need to define your encoding.

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to do is a bit awkward. How ever you can get byte counts per character and then calculate the string length accordingly.

```
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(string);
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(string);
```

Another way to do your investigations, if you really want to try that approach.

```
Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Hello");
```

Answer (score 1):

CharithJ's answer is good, but just for completion.

If you have the requirement of size not content then I suppose you don't need to read/modify the parts separately. If that is the case you don't need them to be in a string but rather a byte[] will be sufficient. That way you don't need the calculation of encoding char size (or even knowing the encoding). You can convert the string to byte[] (byte-to-byte)

```
static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    return bytes;
}
```

Then you can use [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616144/how-can-a-large-array-be-split-into-smaller-arrays) to divide it to parts with less than 1 048 576 (1 MB).